# How to connect to a local SQL server database in asp.net using Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

How do you connect to a local SQL server database in asp.net using Visual Studio 2013? I'm not talking about a remote access connection. In this case, the SQL database is located in the App_Data folder that is at the root of the web application. I want to be able to query the database from the c# file that is connected to the asp.net application and display the data on a label. I have searched for an answer for well over an hour and nothing seems to show up.

Comment: I would think you have to attach it first unless you were using SQL Compact Edition.

Comment: @SteveFerg I created the web application. I created the asp.net page. Then I added database into the App_Data folder. Next I added a few tables in the database. Now I want to query the database from the c# file attached to my asp.net page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your web.config connection string, try something like:

```
<add name="ConnectionStringName"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFileName=c:\inetpub\wwwroot\webite\app_date\DatabaseFileName.mdf;InitialCatalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

(modified accordingly)

Comment: Thank you so much. That was the problem. My connection string was screwed up.